# PySpark textblob from NLTK used in map MissingCorpusError

Tags: apache-spark, nltk, emr, textblob, pyspark

I am trying to implement function for text preprocessing in PySpark. I have amazon EMR where I am installing Python dependencies from the bootstrap script. One of these dependencies is textblob "python -m textblob.download_corpora". Then I am trying to use it locally on all the machines without any problem.

But when I am trying to run it from Spark then I am getting following error:

```
INFO: File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1324, in saveAsTextFile
INFO: keyed._jrdd.map(self.ctx._jvm.BytesToString()).saveAsTextFile(path)
INFO: File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
INFO: File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
INFO: py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o54.saveAsTextFile.
INFO: : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 8 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 8.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 40, ip-172-31-3-125.ec2.internal): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
INFO: File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 79, in main
INFO: serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
INFO: File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 127, in dump_stream
INFO: for obj in iterator:
INFO: File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1316, in func
INFO: for x in iterator:
INFO: File "/home/hadoop/pyckage/package_topics/package_topics/preprocessor.py", line 40, in make_tokens
INFO: File "./package_topics.zip/package_topics/data_utils.py", line 76, in preprocess_text
INFO: for noun_phrase in TextBlob(' '.join(tokens)).noun_phrases
INFO: File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/textblob/decorators.py", line 24, in __get__
INFO: value = obj.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(obj)
INFO: File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/textblob/blob.py", line 431, in noun_phrases
INFO: for phrase in self.np_extractor.extract(self.raw)
INFO: File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/textblob/en/np_extractors.py", line 138, in extract
INFO: self.train()
INFO: File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/textblob/decorators.py", line 38, in decorated
INFO: raise MissingCorpusError()
INFO: MissingCorpusError:
INFO: Looks like you are missing some required data for this feature.
INFO: 
INFO: To download the necessary data, simply run
INFO: 
INFO: python -m textblob.download_corpora
INFO: 
INFO: or use the NLTK downloader to download the missing data: http://nltk.org/data.html
INFO: If this doesn't fix the problem, file an issue at https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues.
INFO: 
INFO: 
INFO: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:124)
INFO: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:154)
INFO: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:87)
INFO: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
INFO: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
INFO: org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
INFO: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
INFO: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
INFO: org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
INFO: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
INFO: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
INFO: org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
INFO: org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
INFO: org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
INFO: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
INFO: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
INFO: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFO: Driver stacktrace:
INFO: at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1185)
INFO: at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1174)
INFO: at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
INFO: at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
INFO: at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
INFO: at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
INFO: at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
INFO: at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
INFO: at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236) 
INFO: at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
INFO: at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1391)
INFO: at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
INFO: at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
INFO: at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
INFO: at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
INFO: at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
INFO: at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
INFO: at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
INFO: at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
INFO: at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I am trying to run both Spark and single node scripts under same user.
Does anybody has some idea what can possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that Spark has internally set home to /home. Hack to make this work with Python is to add before call of textblob line:

```
os.environ['HOME'] = '/home/hadoop'
```

It is connected to this Spark issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4099

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. I'm on an EMR cluster, would that make a difference?